# Not rerunning a dbt table materialization model on parallel runs

Tags: dbt

I am trying to implement a DBT pipeline where more than one DBT runs -- tag will be triggered one after another or concurrently, depending on the file drops. These runs will run daily. Most of the runs have a common upstream model, which is a daily snapshot. To minimize DBT run time of the pipeline, i want to build the upstream model only once.

I have configured the upstream model as a Table and used a macro to check if the model exisits. If no, the model run will happen. If model exits, the model run should be skipped.

It works fine when the model does not exists or want to force a rebuild. but its not able to work when the model exists, it reruns the model code again.

```
{{
  config(
    materialized = "table",
    enabled = check_models_exists(rerun_flag= False) -- Tried this, it did not work
    )
}}

{% if check_model_exists(var("rerun_model_flag")) == True %}

-- MODEL SQL CODE

{% else %}

-- SELCT statement here inserts blank row to the model

{% endif %}
```

--- Macro check_model_exists code

```
{% macro check_model_exists(rerun_model_flag=False) %}


{% if rerun_model_flag == True %}
    {{ log("Model exists, override is set to True, model will be recreated", info=True) }}
    {% do return(true) %}

{% elif rerun_model_flag == False %}
    {%- set source_relation = adapter.get_relation(
      database=this.database,
      schema=this.schema,
      identifier=this.name) -%}

    {% set table_exists=source_relation is not none  %}

    {% if table_exists %}
        {{ log("Model exists and override flag is False. model will not be recreated", info=True) }}
         {% do return(false) %}
    {% else %}
        {{ log("Model does not exist. model will be created", info=True) }}
        {% do return(true) %}
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: You should definitely share the code of that macro `check_model_exists` for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi have added the macro code to the description

Answer (score -1):

I used the DBT incremental model with TIMESTAMP CHECK on current date check to solve the problem